# resurfacing driveway

Tags: staining, ceramic-tile

My driveway needs resurfacing- color change

It is in good condition, no cracks no chips. It does not collect rain water, good run off.

The problem:

As you can see the previous owner did some DYI staining and did a terrible job.

[image: driveway 1]
[image: driveway 2]

The Question:

Do I have to somehow remove the old stain if I want to stain again.. if Yes How?

Is it better to cover it up with some thin pawers or even tiles ?

In preparation for sales, the driveway is the first thing people see.

Comment: Tiles? On the **driveway?** That would kill a sale faster than bad stain job for me...

Comment: Painting would be cheaper - there is paint for this purpose, its called  "concrete and paving paint" around here.

Comment: Have you tried power washing?

Answer (score 1):

Probably just etch it clean and leave it. Trying to guess what the prospective buyer will like for a color is doomed to fail - just get back to clean concrete and stop.